# Why MySQL not using index with where clause

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

I know many people have asked similar questions but i've gone through many of them and cannot find a similar one or at least not one that could help me understand the issue here.

Here's the query -

```
select * from FundTxn force index(fundRRN) 
where fundRRN = 110030234585 and action = 'capture';
```

Here's the DDL -

```
create table FundTxn
(
    fundTxnId bigint auto_increment primary key,
    action varchar(32) null,
    addedOn datetime null,
    tuCreatedOn datetime null,
    tuStatus varchar(32) null,
    fundRRN varchar(255) null,
    fundId bigint null,
    pgdId int null,
    updatedOn datetime null,
    version int default 0 not null,
    constraint fundId
        unique (fundId, txnUpdateId)
);

create index fundRRN
    on FundTxn (fundRRN, action);

create index pgId
    on FundTxn (pgdId, action, tuStatus, tuCreatedOn);
```

Here's the explain -
[image]

This explain doesn't change regardless of whether i use 'use index' or 'force index' or neither. And table size is not in any way less either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using `where fundRRN = '110030234585'` since the column is varchar?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ WOW. IM DUMB. Post an answer i'll accept it.